# Can all irrational numbers be expressed by infinite number series

Tags: sequences-and-series

We already know that the irrational number $\pi$ can be expressed in this way:

$
\pi =4-\frac{4}{2}+\frac{4}{5}+\cdots +\left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}\frac{4}{2n-1}+\cdots=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}\frac{4}{2n-1} 
$

Can all irrational numbers be expressed by infinite number series?
If so, can any transcendental equation have analytic solutions in the form of series?

$$e^{x}+\sin(x)-3=0$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html

Comment: In a sense the answer to the first part of your question is provided by the definition of the real numbers. For example, the decimal expression of a real number is the limit of a sum which converges to it.

But not every real number will have a "nice" or a "regular" form of expansion.

Comment: No. Almost all irrational numbers are transcendental, and almost all transcendental numbers are [noncomputable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^x$ and $\sin x$ both have very simple expansions into infinite series (with rational coefficients). So a series for a solution of $e^x+\sin x-3=0$ can be obtained by the technique of reversion of series. See, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The expansion for $\pi$ should read $\pi/4=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-...+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}+...$ and this (inverse series) expansion can be obtained from the series reversion of the expansion of $\tan(x)$.

Observe that $y = e^x+\sin(x)$ does *not* have an inverse series expansion about $y=0$ because $y=e^x$ does not (its inverse is $\log(y)$). But you can compute the inverse series about other points.

Alternatively, you can compute the inverse series of $u=e^x+\sin(x)-1$ and evaluate the resulting series in $u$ at $u=2$. To make sense, one has to consider the radius of convergence of the resulting inverse series.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general result for small $b$, $a>0$, and other unknown restrictions. It uses [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=factorialpower):

$$e^x+b\sin(cx)=a\implies x=\ln\left(a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\left(-\frac{i b}2\right)^n}{n!}\binom nk (-1)^ka^{2ick-icn-n+1}(ic(2k-n))^{(n-1)}\right)$$

[**Test here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=e%5Ex%2Bb+sin%28c+x%29%2C+x%3Dln%28a%2Bsum%5B%28-+b+%2F2+i%29%5En%2Fn%21%28sum%5Bbinom%28n%2Ck%29%28-1%29%5Ek+a%5E%281+%2B+2+i+c+k+-+n+-+i+c+n%29+factorialpower%28%28i+c+%282+k+-+n%29%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C10%7D%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D%29%2Ca%3D3.0%2Cc%3D2.0%2Cb%3D1%2F2) by substituting

Many numbers can be a series, but what is the inner sum?

Comment: The logarithm can be transformed into the sum using the $g’(x)$ in [this theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem)