# Find solutions to simultaneous equations in two variables (trig and exponential)

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I have the equations $ - e^y \sin(x) + e^x \cos(y) = 0$ and $e^y \cos(x) - e^x \sin(y) = 0$. I'm stuck as to how to find solutions. I have tried grouping the variables on one side, but to no luck because we are mixing exponentials and $\sin$ and $\cos$. I also tried setting them equal to one another but after grouping variables again I don't see an easy (e.g. trig) formula to use here...

For example $$e^y( \sin(x) + \cos(x)) = e^x (\sin(y) + \cos(y))$$ and then $$\frac{e^x}{\sqrt 2} \csc(x+ \frac\pi4) = \frac{e^y}{\sqrt 2} \csc(y+ \frac\pi4)  $$
and then
$$  e^{x-y} = \frac{\sin(y + \frac\pi4)}{\sin (x + \frac\pi4)} $$
but I can't see what to do next other than taking natural log of both sides which doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Are you finding the real and imaginary parts to a complex transcendental equation? Also. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529040/can-all-irrational-numbers-be-expressed-by-infinite-number-series/4581498#4581498) series solution may work.

Comment: Just the real solutions.

Comment: What was meant is that you can simplify the question into $ - e^y \sin(x) + e^x \cos(y) +i (e^y \cos(x) - e^x \sin(y)) = 0+0i\iff e^{\bar z}+ie^z=0,z=x+yi$

Comment: Ah I see - yes I think that works, thanks! :)